# Why is Date.prototype.getTime() giving different values for Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following code,

```
var x = new Date("2016-04-04T00:00:00").getTime();

   console.log(x);
```

The output of `x` is `1459728000000` in Chrome and `1459753200000`in Firefox.

But I want Chrome's output in Firefox too - is there a workaround?

Comment: Webkit default tz seems to be UTC and not for firefox. Be more explicit, see Paulpro's answer.

Comment: @Loenix - Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome defaults to UTC when you don't specify a timezone, while Firefox defaults to your system timezone. Specify that you mean UTC by appending a `Z` to your time:

```
var x = new Date("2016-04-04T00:00:00Z").getTime();
```

Comment: can you cite that?

Comment: @chiliNUT I don't have a reference backing up my claim about the browsers individual implementations, but I can reproduce it on my machine, and I can cite that the [ECMAScript spec leaves it up to the implementation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) if the timezone isn't specified: "If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats."

Comment: @Paulpro - Thank you very much!